# JMM guarantees about final as field and non final reference to the object

Tags: java, concurrency, visibility, final, java-memory-model

I try to understand final fields semantic.

Lets research code:

```
public class App {

    final int[] data;
    static App instance;

    public App() {
        this.data = new int[]{1, 0};
        this.data[1] = 2;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                instance = new App();
            }
        }).start();

        while (instance == null) {/*NOP*/}
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(instance.data));
    }
}
```

I have some questions:

1. Does jmm guarantee, that **if** application terminates then it output [1,2] ?
2. Does jmm guarantee that instance.data not null after loop termination?

**P.S.** I don't know how to make title correct, feel free to edit.

### Additional

Is there visibility difference if we replace:

```
public App() {
    this.data = new int[]{1, 0};
    this.data[1] = 2;
}
```

with

```
public App() {
    int [] data = new int[]{1, 0};
    data[1] = 2;
    this.data = data;    
}
```

also I want to know wjat will be if replace `final`  with volatile in my example.

Thus I want to get explanation about 4 new cases

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, with some catch. You are re-reading the `instance` variable after the loop and since both reads are racy, exiting the loop does not guaranty that the read after the loop reads a non-`null` reference.

Since this issue is not the topic of the question, assume the following change:

```
App instance;
while((instance=App.instance) == null) {/*NOP*/}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(instance.data));
```

Then, *if* application ever terminates, it will output `[1,2]`. The point is that the `final` field semantics applies to the constructor as a whole, the exact time, when the array reference is written to the field, is irrelevant. This also implies that within the constructor, reorderings are possible, so if the `this` reference escapes before the completion of the constructor, all guaranties are void, regardless of whether `this` escapes before or after the writes in program order. Since in your code, `this` does not escape before the constructor’s completion, the guaranty applies.

Refer to [JLS §17.5., `final` Field Semantics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5):

> An object is considered to be *completely initialized* when its constructor finishes. A thread that can only see a reference to an object after that object has been completely initialized is guaranteed to see the correctly initialized values for that object's `final` fields.

Note that it refers to the *completely initialized* state, not the write to the particular `final` fields. This is also addressed in the next section, [§17.5.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5.1):

> Let *o* be an object, and *c* be a constructor for *o* in which a `final` field *f* is written. A freeze action on `final` field *f* of *o* takes place when *c* exits, either normally or abruptly.

---

If you change the variable to `volatile`, you have almost no guarantees at all. A `volatile` field establishes a *happens-before* relationship between a write to that variable and a subsequent read, but the often overlooked key point is the word “*subsequent*”. If the `App` instance is improperly published, like in your example, there is no guaranty that the main thread’s read of `instance.data` will be subsequent. If it reads a `null` reference, which is now possible, then you know that it is not subsequent. If it reads a non-`null` reference, you know that it is subsequent to the field write, which implies that you are guaranteed to read the `1` in the first slot, but for the second you may read `0` or `2`.

If you want to discuss this in terms of barriers and reordering, the `volatile` write to `data` guarantees that all previous writes are committed, which includes the write of `1` to the first array slot, but it doesn’t guaranty that subsequent non-`volatile` writes are not committed earlier. So it is still possible that the improper publication of the `App` reference is performed before the `volatile` write (though that rarely happens).

If you move the write to the end of the constructor, all previous writes are visible once a non-`null` array reference is seen. For `final` fields, it doesn’t need further discussions, as said above, the actual placement of the write within the constructor is irrelevant anyway. For the `volatile` case, as said above, you are not guaranteed to read a non-`null` reference, but when you read it, all previous writes are committed. It might be helpful to know that the expression `new int[]{1, 0};` gets compiled to the equivalent of `hiddenVariable=new int[2]; hiddenVariable[0]=1; hiddenVariable[1]=0;` anyway. Placing another array write after its construction but before the `volatile` write of the array reference to the field, doesn’t change the semantics.

Comment: the non-escaping + the `StoreStore` barrier for final fields, that is why the `[1,2]` output.

Comment: @Holger, I want to know your opinion about http://stackoverflow.com/q/41983725/2674303

Comment: @gstackoverflow: I think that question has been answered by John Vint. Generally, you should not confuse object visibility (like `private` or `protected`) with thread visibility. When another thread can concurrently invoke the method accessing the private field, you can have a data race.

Comment: @Holger, by mind I think like you say but it contradicted with feeling thus I was not sure. Thanks for proove

Comment: @Holger,I am sorry, but I want to reask one more time because all colleagues say different and your quotes doesn't ask me directly. I can treat it as I want.

Comment: @Holger oh, sorry, I forgot to add that this question added to the topic

Comment: **Adding another this.data = data; assignment is not only meaningless, it’s simply not allowed, if data is final.** surely I mean that inline declaration will be reduced.

Comment: Right, difference not spotted well enough. Hope it answers it now.

Comment: @Holger while I like this answer a lot (your wording is absolutely fantastic sometimes), I would like to add that final introduces a `StoreStore` barrier that does not allow the publishing of the reference to be reordered with any other field Store in the constructor; while the volatile store preceded by any other non-volatile store does not introduce any barrier; that is why the volatile field has no guarantees of re-orderings. Of course, 1+

Comment: @Eugene: I usually avoid explaining the JMM in terms of these barriers, as they do not appear in the specification at all. The “JSR-133 Cookbook” is very interesting to those planning to write a compiler or optimizer, but not so much for an application developer. I’m curious about the changes that might come with Java 9, as with it, explicit fences become part of the API. Since this should be reflected in the specification, it might affect, how to explain it in the future…

Comment: @Holger exactly my point. fences are part of jdk-9, seems like it's about time to start mentioning those as well.

Comment: @Eugene: as said, I wait for an official specification, I can refer to. You might have noticed that I try carefully to use exactly the same words as the specification when I mean the same, as a lot of these words are heavily overloaded when used colloquially and this is a topic, where it is too easy to create additional confusion…

Comment: @Holger, I think NullPointerException is also a possible outcome. Even if `instance == null` check returns `false` and the loop terminates, the JMM does not guarantee that `instance.data` sees the non-null reference to `instance`. Guarantees provided for `final` fields are formulated using Memory Chain partial order: in simplest case a memory-chain edge appears _if_ a read happens to see the result of a write. These memory-chain edges are not transitive with respect to program order, so one read seeing the result of a write does not guarantee that another reed will see the same result.

Comment: I tried to summarize my perspective in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62278680/can-object-access-be-reordered-with-that-objects-final-field-access-in-java

Comment: @NikitaTkachenko yes, definitely. It struck me immediately when seeing this old Q&A, even before reading your comment. It seems, I was too much focused on the `data` field, which the question was about, so I missed the problem with the double-read of the `instance` field. I’ll update the answer.