# How deep volatile publication guarantees?

Tags: java, concurrency, visibility, volatile, happens-before

As is known guarant that if we have some object reference and this reference has final field - we will see all reachable fields from final field(at least when constructor was finished)

### example 1:

```
class Foo{
    private final Map map;
     Foo(){
         map = new HashMap();
         map.put(1,"object");
     }

     public void bar(){
       System.out.println(map.get(1));
     }
}
```

As I undertand at this case we have guarantee that `bar()` method always output `object` because:
1. I listed full code of class `Foo` and map is final;
**2. If some thread will see reference of `Foo` and this reference != null, then we have guarantees that reachable from final `map` reference value will be actual**.

also I think that

### Example 2:

```
class Foo {
    private final Map map;
    private Map nonFinalMap;

    Foo() {
        nonFinalMap = new HashMap();
        nonFinalMap.put(2, "ololo");
        map = new HashMap();
        map.put(1, "object");
    }

    public void bar() {
        System.out.println(map.get(1));
    }

    public void bar2() {
        System.out.println(nonFinalMap.get(2));
    }
}
```

here we have same gurantees about `bar()` method but `bar2` can throw `NullPointerException` despite `nonFinalMap` assignment occurs before `map`  assignment.

I want to know how about volatile:

### Example 3:

```
class Foo{
        private volatile Map map;
         Foo(){
             map = new HashMap();
             map.put(1,"object");
         }

         public void bar(){
           System.out.println(map.get(1));
         }
    }
```

As I understand `bar()` method cannot throw `NullPoinerException` but it can print `null`; (I am fully not sure about this aspect)

### Example 4:

```
class Foo {
    private volatile Map map;
    private Map nonVolatileMap;

    Foo() {
        nonVolatileMap= new HashMap();
        nonVolatileMap.put(2, "ololo");
        map = new HashMap();
        map.put(1, "object");
    }

    public void bar() {
        System.out.println(map.get(1));
    }

    public void bar2() {
        System.out.println(nonFinalMap.get(2));
    }
}
```

I think here we have same gurantees about `bar()` method also `bar2()` cannot throw `NullPointerException` because `nonVolatileMap` assignment written higher volatile map assignment but it can output null

---

**Added** after  Elliott Frisch comment

**Publication through race example:**

```
public class Main {
    private static Foo foo;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                foo = new Foo();
            }
        }).start();


        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (foo == null) ; // empty loop

                foo.bar();
            }
        }).start();

    }
}
```

Please proove or correct my comments to code snippets.

Comment: No caller can access the `map` (and there are no methods to write to the `map`) so I'm confused as to why you are concerned about threads.

Comment: @Elliott Frisch which example are you discuss? also read following:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41955348/jmm-guarantees-about-final-as-field-and-non-final-reference-to-the-object and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41983725/final-and-private-combination-addes-visibility-guaranties

Comment: @user889742 Thanks, fixed. looks like I am tired

Comment: @Elliott Frisch I have added example of race publication

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In the realm of current Java Memory Model, `volatile` does not equal `final`. In other words, [you cannot replace `final` with `volatile`](https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/close-encounters-of-jmm-kind/#wishful-volatiles-are-finals), and think the safe construction guarantees are the same. Notably, this can theoretically happen:

```
public class M {
  volatile int x;
  M(int v) { this.x = v; }
  int x() { return x; }
}

// thread 1
m = new M(42);

// thread 2
M lm;
while ((lm = m) == null); // wait for it
print(lm.x()); // allowed to print "0"
```

So, writing the `volatile` field in constructor is not as safe.

**Intuition:** there is a race on `m` in the example above. That race is not eliminated by making the *field* `M.x` `volatile`, only making the `m` itself `volatile` would help. In other words, `volatile` modifier in that example is at the *wrong place* to be useful. In safe publication, you have to have "writes -> volatile write -> volatile read that observes volatile write ->  reads (now observing writes prior the volatile write)", and instead you have "volatile write -> write -> read -> volatile read (that does not observe the volatile write)".

**Trivia 1:** This property means we can optimize `volatile`-s much more aggressively in constructors. This corroborates the intuition that unobserved volatile store (and indeed it is not observed until constructor with non-escaping `this` finishes) can be relaxed.

**Trivia 2:** This also means you cannot safely initialize `volatile` variables. Replace `M` with `AtomicInteger` in the example above, and you have a peculiar real-life behavior! Call `new AtomicInteger(42)` in one thread, publish the instance unsafely, and do `get()` in another thread -- are you guaranteed to observe `42`? JMM, as stated, says "nope". Newer revisions of Java Memory Model strive to guarantee safe construction for all initializations, to capture this case. And many non-x86 ports where that matters [have already strengthened this](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/hotspot/file/c22bf83dad09/src/share/vm/opto/parse1.cpp#l966) to be safe.

**Trivia 3:** [Doug Lea](https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/close-encounters-of-jmm-kind/#_footnote_12): "This `final` vs `volatile` issue has led to some twisty constructions in java.util.concurrent to allow 0 as the base/default value in cases where it would not naturally be. This rule sucks and should be changed."

That said, the example can be made more cunning:

```
public class C {
  int v;
  C(int v) { this.x = v; }
  int x() { return x; }    
}

public class M {
  volatile C c;
  M(int v) { this.c = new C(v); }
  int x() { 
    while (c == null); // wait!
    return c.x();
  }
}

// thread 1
m = new M(42);

// thread 2
M lm;
while ((lm = m) == null); // wait for it
print(lm.x()); // always prints "42"
```

If there is a transitive read through `volatile` field *after* volatile read observed the value written by volatile write in constructor, the usual safe publication rules kick in.

Comment: almost clear for me. But I didn't catch **Trivia 2** and Which behaviour would be in case of AtomicInteger usage

Comment: Call `new AtomicInteger(42)` in one thread, publish it unsafely, and do `get()` in another thread -- are you guaranteed to observe `42`? JMM, as stated, says "nope".

Comment: because AtomicInteger just wrapper over volatile int ?

Comment: Yes. See the symmetry between `AtomicInteger` and `M` from the example.

Comment: Just to clarify - in your first example, even if we had `final int x;` instead of `volatile`, are we guaranteed to see 42 in thread 2? By my knowledge, I would say no. What confuses me is the `m` variable - if it is _not_ `volatile`, the `while` loop might loop forever. Or we could see a partially constructed `M` instance, could we not? JCIP taught me that one visibility error spreads all over you if you try to just roll with it...

Comment: @Petr Janeček I am fully sure that in case of final in first example you have guaratees to see  42

Comment: @Petr Janeček if you see non nul reference, you could be sure that object (where reference points) final fields have initialized already and you wiil see it from any thread

Comment: Yeah, changing `volatile` to `final` precludes `0` as the result. That's the whole reason for `final`-s to exist: to survive data races.

Comment: @PetrJaneček: "What confuses me is the m variable - if it is not volatile, the while loop might loop forever." Oh, OPs example had a loop, and I tried to match that. But this is actually a teachable moment: the fact that compilers _may_ reduce non-volatile loop into the infinite one, does not mean they _should_ do it. JMM only says what results can a compliant implementation print out in that example: for non-volatile loop, it says {nothing, 0, 42}.

Comment: @Aleksey, please help me to answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42364006/why-safepoint-class-from-%D1%81oncurrency-in-practice-book-marked-as-threadsafe